# HTML5 vs Transitional 1.0 Different height of cell?

Tags: html, xhtml

My code looks like this:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td><img with height 27px></td>
<td><img with height 27px></td>
<td><img with height 27px></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Now using firebug I can see that if I declare page as Transitional XHTML 1.0 the height of all three td elements is 27px. But if I switch page to HTML5  I get height 29px.

Could somebody please tell me the reason why this cold happen? Even suggestions for further investigations might do.

I am using FF v17 and MSVS2k8 WebDev server (for ASP.NET).

Thanks.

Comment: Use a CSS reset. That's what they're for.

Comment: Actually I do have CSS reset in place. This is after :/

Comment: This question is asked in various guises very regularly. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Images,_Tables,_and_Mysterious_Gaps for an explanation, or search SO for "under img".

Comment: @Alohci, I think you should turn your comment into an answer. This is clearly a case where “Almost Standards” mode strikes.

Comment: @Alohci Thank you for your solution. Please feel free to repost is as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Explanation can be found here (ignore the images which are messed-up):
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Images,_Tables,_and_Mysterious_Gaps

Quick solution can be found here (I used to display: block; for images in cells):
http://www.visibilityinherit.com/code/gap-under-image-example.php

Credit goes to Alohci, who replied as comment to my question.

@Alohci: Thanks for your solution, feel free to repost the comment as answer and I will accept it.

Comment: You should reply to Alohci in the comments if you would like him to post the answer instead. He won't be notified when you @ him here in the answers.